# How to get char input from user, and place in a certain memory location?

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to know why my code isn't working if thats ok. Whats supposed to happen is it is supposed to get 9 chars from the user and put them into allocated memory locations.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
char count, *ptr, *p;

ptr = malloc(27);

p = ptr;


for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  *p++ = scanf("%c", &count);
 }

  *p = '\0';
  puts(ptr);
  free(ptr);

}
```

Comment: Change `*p++ = scanf("%c", &count);` to `scanf("%c", &p[i]);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following issues.

1. I assume you want to store characters in memory pointed by ptr. Why are you allocating 27 bytes? You should allocate for 9 characters.

   `ptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*(9+1));// 1 for '\0'`
   `if(0 == ptr)`
       `return;`
2. Scanf returns number of characters read. So you should write scanf like below.

   `scanf("%c", p++);`
3. If you want to enter string using scanf, you can use "%s". Loop is not actually required.

   `scanf("%9[^\n]",p);`

Make these changes. It should work.

Comment: I don't know why I am not able to format my code :( Sorry.

Comment: because SO markdown has a bug that prevents code blocks to work with bullets/numbering

Comment: @Rohan, How did you do it?!

Comment: I did two edit, In first i used combination of `blockquote` and `{ }`. In second i used combination of  grave accent (`) and `<br/>'.

Answer (score 0):

scanf(" %c", &count), a space before %c,  will help you to skip newline